como hacer procedimiento o rutina con tabla de campos de lista
Tengo unos datos en una tabla de sql server , con campos como lista, es decir tengo un concepto (string) y un importe (float), de la siguiente manera, concepto01, importe01, concepto02, importe02,y asi hasta el 35 pero para el ejemplo lo simplifica hasta el 5.
quiero buscar en los campo concepto que sea 'P' si es cierto sumo los importes lo tengo asi
declare @@concepto01  varchar(2)
declare @@concepto02  varchar(2)
declare @@concepto03  varchar(2)
declare @@concepto04  varchar(2)
declare @@concepto05  varchar(2)

declare @@importe01 float
declare @@importe02 float
declare @@importe03 float
declare @@importe04 float
declare @@importe05 float

BEGIN
DECLARE lee_cur INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
select concepto01, concepto02, concepto03, concepto04, concepto05,
importe01, importe02, importe03, importe04, importe05 
from tno_nomina

OPEN lee_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM lee_cur INTO 
@@concepto01, @@concepto02, @@concepto03, @@concepto04, @@concepto05, 
@@importe01,  @@importe02,  @@importe03,   @@importe04,  @@importe05 

    WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN

if @@cpto01 = 'P'
begin
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + @@importe01
end
if @@cpto02 = 'P'
begin
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + @@importe02
end
if @@cpto03 = 'P'
begin
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + @@importe03
end
if @@cpto04 = 'P'
begin
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + @@importe04
end
if @@cpto05 = 'P'
begin
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + @@importe05
end
 END                    
        
    FETCH NEXT FROM lee_cur INTO 
@@concepto01, @@concepto02, @@concepto03, @@concepto04, @@concepto05, 
@@importe01,  @@importe02,  @@importe03,   @@importe04,  @@importe05 

END 
DEALLOCATE lee_cur

pero son 35 conceptos , entonces para no tener el conjunto de "ifs" ni hacer un case o select case enorme
quiero simplificar la parte de los ifs de la siguiente manera.
        select @total = 1
        declare @total int

        WHILE @total <= 35
        BEGIN
            if @total <10 
            BEGIN
                select @t = '0'+ convert(varchar,@total)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                select @t =  convert(varchar,@total)
            END

      if (convert(varchar(12),'@@concepto'+@t) = 'P')
      begin
       print ' es percepcion ' + convert(varchar(12),'@@concepto'+@t)
  @@total_perc = @@total_perc + convert(varchar(12),'@@concepto'+@t)
      end
     
     set @total = @total + 1

Pero a la hora de ejecutar me dice el siguiente mensaje
Mens. 137, Nivel 15, Estado 2, Línea 1
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@@concepto01".
Mens. 137, Nivel 15, Estado 2, Línea 1
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@@importe01".

lo que deseo hacer es minimizar el tamaño del codigo porque como comente tiene 35 campos enumerados de concepto y de importe, la cadena si la forma ej. concepto01, importe01,  pero no toma en cuenta el valor como si fuera una instruccion .

Si lo que quieres es minimizar el código, lo que necesitas es eliminar el cursor. No solo tendrás menos código, también será más eficiente.
SELECT @total_perc = @total_perc 
                   + IIF( concepto01 = 'P', importe01, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto02 = 'P', importe02, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto03 = 'P', importe03, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto04 = 'P', importe04, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto05 = 'P', importe05, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto06 = 'P', importe06, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto07 = 'P', importe07, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto08 = 'P', importe08, 0)
                   + IIF( concepto09 = 'P', importe09, 0)
FROM tno_nomina;

Si lo haces de esa forma, puedes copiar, pegar y reemplazar sin problemas. Podrías usar código dinámico pero no aporta en mucho. En todo caso, lo que tendrías que hacer es normalizar tu tabla para evitar tener 35 grupos de columnas.
Si realmente deseas usar código dinámico y tus columnas son realmente repetitivas, puedes usar algo similar a esto.
DECLARE @total_perc float = 0;
DECLARE @SQL        nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @SQL += REPLICATE( ' ', 19) + '+ IIF( ' + CC.name + ' = ''P'', ' + CI.name + ', 0)' + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.columns CC
JOIN sys.columns CI ON CC.object_id = CI.object_id AND RIGHT( CC.name, 2) = RIGHT( CI.name, 2)
WHERE CC.object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'tno_nomina')
AND CC.name LIKE 'concepto__'
AND CI.name LIKE 'importe__';

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @total_perc = @total_perc ' + CHAR(10)
         + @SQL + 'FROM tno_nomina;';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@total_perc float OUTPUT', @total_perc OUTPUT;

SELECT @total_perc;

Al final, generará un código igual al que puedes generar manualmente, pero va a tener un costo extra por consultar los nombres de las columnas y armar el código. El código siempre será igual puesto que no puedes eliminar columnas antes de consultar la tabla y si la consultas al momento de generar el código, será mucho más costoso ya que tienes que leer cada fila 36 veces (35 para ver el concepto y una más para sumar los importes).
